# How do I read in all of the nodes in an XML Document?

Tags: xml, vba

I'm trying to display all of the nodes in an xml document. The code I have thus far (shown below) only displays the two child nodes of the root node, which is a problem because the majority of the child nodes have child nodes as well.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
Sub countXMLNodes()

Dim xDoc As DOMDocument
Set xDoc = New DOMDocument
If Not xDoc.Load(filepath) Then
    MsgBox ("failed to load xml document")
End If

Dim list As IXMLDOMNodeList
Set list = xDoc.SelectNodes("//PropertiesAndDocument")


Dim node As IXMLDOMNode
Dim childNode As IXMLDOMNode

For Each node In list
    If (node.HasChildNodes) Then
        For Each childNode In node.ChildNodes
            MsgBox (childNode.BaseName)
        Next childNode
    End If
Next node

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe you also want to expand a little bit on your question explaining what you want to achieve: do you want to count all nodes in your XML file, or do you want to count only the nodes which actually contain a value? (maybe add an example + expected output, for example `<lv1>
 <lv2>
  <lv3>
   <lv4> test4 </lv4>
   <lv4> test4.2 </lv4>
  </lv3>
 </lv2> 
 <lv2> test 2 </lv2>
</lv1>`

Comment: @Yohsoog For now, I only want to count each of the nodes. Eventually, I will be putting all of the nodes into a list where the user of the program can tick which nodes they want to remove from the XML file. I have a rough idea how I will do the latter part, but I need to be able to iterate through all of the nodes first in order to add them to a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to adjust the following example code to work for your intended purpose:

```
Public Sub LoadDocument()
Dim xDoc As DOMDocument
Set xDoc = New DOMDocument
xDoc.validateOnParse = False
If xDoc.Load("c:/temp/tmp/test.xml") Then
   ' The document loaded successfully.
   ' Now do something intersting.
   DisplayNode xDoc.ChildNodes, 0
Else
   ' The document failed to load.
   ' See the previous listing for error information.
End If
End Sub

Public Sub DisplayNode(ByRef Nodes As IXMLDOMNodeList, _
   ByVal Indent As Integer)

   Dim xNode As IXMLDOMNode
   Indent = Indent + 2

   For Each xNode In Nodes
      Debug.Print Space$(Indent) & xNode.ParentNode.NODENAME & _
        ":" & xNode.nodeTypeString & ":" & xNode.NodeValue

      If xNode.HasChildNodes Then
         DisplayNode xNode.ChildNodes, Indent
      End If
   Next xNode
End Sub
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx#beginner_howuse

I came across this example while adjusting your code for recursion. It seems to me it's better for me to share the original example so you can try to figure it out yourself with it. Let me know if it's still not clear.

I changed a small part of the code above to work towards your goal of listing all the XML elements (I use debug.print, you can add them to your list). For the following example:

`<lv1>
 <lv2>
  <lv3>
   <lv4> test4 </lv4>
   <lv4> test4.2 </lv4>
  </lv3>
 </lv2> 
 <lv2> test 2 </lv2>
</lv1>`

This gives the next result:

`#document:element:
    lv1:element:
      lv2:element:
        lv3:element:
          lv4:text: test4 
        lv3:element:
          lv4:text: test4.2 
    lv1:element:
      lv2:text: test 2`

Comment: I'm still having trouble. That seems to me like it would present the same issue of not finding the child nodes of other child nodes? @Yohsoog

Comment: The code above should go as deep as the deepest child node because of recursion: you can see in the code that ´ If xNode.HasChildNodes ` the same function is used again. Can you explain in more detail where you are having problems?

Comment: Does my slightly changed code and example help you any more?

Comment: Yes it has, thank you for spending the time to go through it with me @Yohsoog

Comment: I see you changed your comment. No problem, you're welcome, I hope it really did help. It wasn't that I didn't want to provide a complete code answer, but that I couldn't. For example I didn't know if you wanted to count the LV3 double (as in my example) or not. Also to give you the code for counting the elements would bring you further from your goal (the list) then my example above I believe. And in your list, I didn't know if you wanted to have a complete list, or any element of a certain level only mentioned once. Anyway, glad it helped.

Comment: Yes, upon re-reading it I saw how rude I came across and that it wouldn't have helped me much anyway if you could have done what I asked. I can only apologise, this is for work so I've been getting a bit stressed, but that's no excuse.